# How to make ubuntu respect my choice of keyboard layout when keyboard is replugged

Tags: keyboard-layout

I've found that if I disconnect my USB keyboard and reconnects it it seem to resort to using "standard" US layout, but I want US intl. layout ([the same layout as in windows](http://kbdlayout.info/kbdusx)). In order to make that happen I have to after I reconnect the keyboard select another layout and then US intl. which is rather annoying since it means that I have to do this rain-dance each time I connect the keyboard (besides I also have to have another keyboard layout installed that I don't intend to use, but have to have in order to change the layout).

I've tried to run `dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration`, but with no luck.

Before I disconnect the keyboard, with appropriate keymap I get:

```
> cat /etc/default/keyboard 
# KEYBOARD CONFIGURATION FILE

# Consult the keyboard(5) manual page.

XKBMODEL="pc105"
XKBLAYOUT="us"
XKBVARIANT="intl"
XKBOPTIONS="lv3:ralt_switch"

BACKSPACE="guess"

> localectl status
   System Locale: LANG=en_US.UTF-8
                  LANGUAGE=en_US:en
                  LC_NUMERIC=sv_SE.UTF-8
                  LC_TIME=sv_SE.UTF-8
                  LC_MONETARY=sv_SE.UTF-8
                  LC_PAPER=sv_SE.UTF-8
                  LC_NAME=sv_SE.UTF-8
                  LC_ADDRESS=sv_SE.UTF-8
                  LC_TELEPHONE=sv_SE.UTF-8
                  LC_MEASUREMENT=sv_SE.UTF-8
                  LC_IDENTIFICATION=sv_SE.UTF-8
       VC Keymap: n/a
       X11 Layout: us
       X11 Model: pc105
       X11 Variant: intl
       X11 Options: lv3:ralt_switch

> setxkbmap -print
xkb_keymap {
    xkb_keycodes  { include "evdev+aliases(qwerty)" };
    xkb_types     { include "complete"  };
    xkb_compat    { include "complete"  };
    xkb_symbols   { include "pc+us(intl)+inet(evdev)+level3(ralt_switch)"   };
    xkb_geometry  { include "pc(pc105)" };
};
```

But after disconnecting the keyboard and reconnecting it gives:

```
> localectl status
   System Locale: LANG=en_US.UTF-8
          LANGUAGE=en_US:en
          LC_NUMERIC=sv_SE.UTF-8
          LC_TIME=sv_SE.UTF-8
          LC_MONETARY=sv_SE.UTF-8
          LC_PAPER=sv_SE.UTF-8
          LC_NAME=sv_SE.UTF-8
          LC_ADDRESS=sv_SE.UTF-8
          LC_TELEPHONE=sv_SE.UTF-8
          LC_MEASUREMENT=sv_SE.UTF-8
          LC_IDENTIFICATION=sv_SE.UTF-8
   VC Keymap: n/a
  X11 Layout: us
   X11 Model: pc105
 X11 Variant: intl
 X11 Options: lv3:ralt_switch
> setxkbmap -print
xkb_keymap {
    xkb_keycodes  { include "evdev+aliases(qwerty)" };
    xkb_types     { include "complete"  };
    xkb_compat    { include "complete"  };
    xkb_symbols   { include "pc+us(altgr-intl)+inet(evdev)+level3(ralt_switch)" };
    xkb_geometry  { include "pc(pc105)" };
};

> gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.input-sources sources
[('xkb', 'se+dvorak'), ('xkb', 'se'), ('xkb', 'us')]
```

I note that `localectl status` doesn't seem to tell the truth here. `setxkbmap -print` however seem to tell that the keymap is no longer the same (and not what I think I requested in `/etc/default/keymap`)

It turned out that there were two places that one could configure the layout: in Settings > Keyboard > Layout and in the thingy on the statusline where you can switch current layout has Configuration > Input Methods. It turned out that the former contained a layout that I didn't want. Setting the layout there to to use US intl seemed to solve my problem.

Now the remaining question is more of curiosity, some explanation of this behavior (why, how etc). Should I take further action?

Comment: My first thought is that you should have exactly the variant you want to use in `/etc/default/keyboard` (or the `localectl` output). Please note that there are quite a few English US variants, and that `altgr-intl` is not the same as `intl`.

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson Thanks, it seem to be that `intl` is the layout I want, but changing so that `/etc/default/keyboard`  points to that doesn't seem to solve the issue here (although `localectl` seem to say that it is)

Comment: For some (to me unknown) reason there's TWO places where one can configure the keyboard layout. First there's Settings > Keyboard > Layout, but also there's in the language/layout selection on the statusbar that has Configuration > Input Methods. I guess these would need to be kept in sync or Murphy's law will make Ubuntu chose the configuration you don't want:(

Comment: Good that you figured it out. This part: "the thingy on the statusline where you can switch current layout has Configuration > Input Methods" confuses me, though. As far as I know the input source indicator in the top bar does not have any "Configuration" option. Maybe you can show a screenshot or something?

Comment: I right clicked on it and there's preferences which brings up a window called "IBus Preferences" where there is a Input Method tab where I can add layouts.

Comment: In that case you are not on standard Ubuntu, right? Ubuntu Budgie maybe?

Comment: Standard Ubuntu 22.04 LTS, but using xfce if that matters

Comment: Actually it matters a lot!! If you had mentioned that in your question or via a tag, some confusion during our conversation could have been avoided.